# Simplify $p\lor q\lor(\neg p\land\neg q\land r)$ to $p\lor q\lor r$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to simplify the logic expression:
$$p\lor q\lor(\neg p\land\neg q\land r)$$
with laws of logic to get: 
$$p\lor q\lor r$$
I have no idea how to get to the result by using the laws of logic. Help!

Comment: Use [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Comment: Can you show me?

Answer (score 3):

$$p\lor q\lor(\neg p\land\neg q\land r)$$
Use the distributive law:
$$=(p\lor q\lor\neg p)\land(p\lor q\lor\neg q)\land(p\lor q\lor r)$$
Complementarity ($p\lor\neg p=1$) reduces the first two terms to 1:
$$=1\land1\land(p\lor q\lor r)$$
Identity ($p\land1=p$) eliminates those 1s:
$$=p\lor q\lor r$$

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that

Comment: @KyleClicquennoi What? This _is_ the answer.

Comment: Yea sorry but I saw that there is $p \lor \lnot p$ and $q \lor \lnot q$ In the first two terms. Should I use the inverse law and then then the domination  law or just the absorption law?

Comment: Yes I do, I just did it differently. Using the commutative law on the first term then the inverse law on both terms to make it $p \lor T_0$ and $q \lor T_0$. I then used the domination law and then identify law to get where you are. It’s how my book wanted it

Comment: Absorption.  $a\vee(\neg a\wedge b)=a\vee b$